# Select nav option not going to URL rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am a little confused as to why the follwing is not working, I have tried 2 pieces of jquery/javascript

So I have a a dropdown menu for my mobile view 9 I have incorporated the two ways i have tried to create a link

```
   <select id="nav-select">
    <option value="/public_pages/faq">FAQ</option>
    <option value="vacancy"><%= link_to 'Create Vacancy ', new_vacancy_path %></option>        
   </select>
```

The JavaScript I have tried to get the window location and link to the correct url

```
$('#nav-select').change(function(){
var url = $(this).val();
window.location = url;
});

document.getElementById("nav-select").addEventListener('change',function () {
window.location = this.value;
 },false);
```

When i select an option nothing happens

Any ideas anyone? Am i using the select tags incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: Try putting your code within document ready handler.

Comment: thanks, but that doesnt work..this should work shouldn’t it?

Comment: hang on, spoke to soon, all working, mark as answer if you like and ill accept, simple error it seems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848164/undefined) stated, putting your script inside a document ready handler will resolve this. 
To explain further, I would bet you defined the script before the actual document markup. This will have jQuery search for an element that does not yet exist in the document.

By putting it inside a document ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav-select').change(function(){
        var url = $(this).val();
        window.location = url;
    });
});
```

you are essentially having the script wait until the page is done loading, and the `#nav-select` element exists in the document before executing your code.